# Increment passing TTL

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

My ISP sends me packets with TTL = 1 to limit the distribution to my PC. I need to change TTL for all packets going through my PC to a static (eg 128) or increased value.

OS: Win 7

Comment: Do you only have one IP address and need to do NAT? Also, what does this have to do with wireless networking?

Comment: I have static IP and I want to share internet from PC to mobile devices over WIFi.

Comment: Then just connect a router to the ISP and the PC to the router.

Comment: I don't have a router.

Comment: Spend the $30-$50 and get one. Desktops make lousy routers when they are also being used as desktops. Try to find one that can run alternate firmware like DD-WRT or Tomato.

Comment: Must be not expensive way to solve this problem on program level.

Comment: Yes, but the result will be lousy. Desktops make lousy routers when they're also being used as desktops. When the PC is busy with things like graphics and audio, latency on the network is terrible because of load. And when the PC is not busy, latency is spiky and awful because of power management. A dedicated WiFi router is worth every penny.

Comment: But I used this way of internet sharing before moment when ISP created limitation and I had high stable speed. I want to return that times, I just must change this TTL.

Comment: While you may have had great speed, if you attempt to now actually "mangle" packets using your desktop, there will be a decrease in network performance. I would note that paying for the router will be well worth it as it will allow you to extend your network cheaply. That being said try using the [Windows Packet Filter Kit](http://www.ntkernel.com/?Products:Development_Toolkits:Windows_Packet_Filter_Kit)